# Connecting to server from remote machine

Tags: linux, windows, windows-server-2008, networking

I wish to connect my machine to a server in some other city. For doing the same I am using the following command:

```
         mstsc -v ip_address_of_server

   remote desktop can't connect to remote computer for one of these reasons:
   1) Remote access to server is not enabled.
   2) Remote computer is turned off
   3) Remote computer is not available on network.
   Make sure remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.
```

As per previous posts I need to turn off my client computers firewall..which I have...but still it gives me the same message.

Can someone please please help me out...so as to how i may resolve this?? I am really new to networking, etc.

Also when i am pinging:

```
 ping ip_address_of server
```

I am getting the following response:

Reply from ip_address_of_server: destination host unreachable

Also I did try on ubuntu with rdesktop...still its not been able to connect with it.

Also i know there are other people who are able to connect their machines with the server remotely. So i guess its not working for me only. Also when I accessed the same machine through LAN I was able to do so.

Comment: Contact the system administrator.

Comment: You need to add some more detail - for example the exact IP you are connecting to, and connecting from (blank the last octet with X'es if you want to)

Answer (score 1):

Your host (remote box) is inaccessible, and you should do what's written in the first error report.

Verify that the remote computer is running, that the remote desktop service is running, if it's accessible via the given IP and if firewall rules allow connection to port tcp/3389 (remote desktop).

There could also be another firewall, or it might needs additional rules if it's behind NAT (port forwarding). There might also be an output firewall policy on your local network, which forbids connecting to remote locations via remote-desktop protocol.

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying...but i know there are other people who are able to connect their machines with the server remotely. So i guess its not working for me only. Also when I accessed the same machine through LAN I was able to do so.